# Использовать 12 -колоночную и 7-колоночную систему в одном макете

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как я понял Bootstrap устроен на 12 колоночном макете...
Cтили по умолчанию:

```
.container{width:940px}

.span12 {
    width: 940px;
}
```

Ну а если я хочу макет жесткий не `940px` а `900px`.Тогда как использовать эти `span1-12`.Они ведь только для ширины `940px` или я ошибаюсь?

Возможно в одном макете использовать 12 -колоночную и 7-колоночную систему?

Comment: а правильно не взяли. зачем в конторах ваши наколенные поделки ? они может и прекрасны, только стоят по времени с половину проекта.

Answer (score 2):

1) Бутстрап - основа. Можете переписать стили на less, можете через em и проценты.  
2) контейнером можно обернуть маленький кусок сайта. 940 пикселей - это нормальная максимальная ширина для ОДНОГО элемента, после чего он становится слабо юзабельным. Ну, пожалуй, до 102- можно догнать, но не более.
3) бутстрап требуют, так как на нем можно гарантированно получить быстрый непротивный дизайн. Сколько провозится программист на чистых языках - никому не известно. Фреймворки - они такие.

Comment: со вторым пунктом несогласен, эта мода на узенькие сайты при повальных широкоформатных мониторах уже достала.

Comment: Еще раз. Не весь сайт узкий. Таких колонок по 940 может быть хоть 10.
Просто, например, текст, шириной более 80-100 em читать уже не очень удобно лично мне.  
А широкие элементы, вроде горизонтального меню или картинок можно либо не оборачивать, либо вручную задавать ширину. Таких элементов не очень много:)

Я не спорю, что европейская школа диза предполагает узкие сайты целиком. Причем часто совсем неризиновые. Но это не значит, что бутстрап можно использовать только так.

Comment: я вообще бы за выбор юзером, меня например нисколько не обламывает форум на всю ширину экрана, и сильно обламывает на 1/3 её